# How to create a process which is hidden from task manager, using Windows API?

Tags: c++, windows, process

I want to create a process which should be hidden from task managers. It should NOT be done by writing to another process's memory, rather it should be an independent process. I have to use Windows API, and I will write code in c++ most probably.

Comment: There is no Windows API to hide a process from Task Manager. Such a task is accomplished by malware/rootkits by hooking system APIs like `EnumProcesses()`, `Zw/NtQuerySystemInformation()`, etc - tasks that are likely to trigger red flags by anti-virus/anti-malware tools. So just don't do it. There is rarely a legitimate reason for non-malware to hide a process from Task Manager.

Comment: yeah, you are right. I just think it would be interesting to see how it works. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.